# Connecting github repository with google cloud, push at the same time as well as commits

Tags: github, google-cloud-platform, repository

I want to connect my GitHub repository to an already made google cloud project with the exact same documents.
I have been searching and using Google Cloud build, but I need docker, the problem is I don't have any container or docker file in the repository.
I know it's made with triggers and pipes, but i don't know how, I am pretty new to this.

Is there something I could do, or is impossible?
All the docs in google cloud are in SSH.

Comment: Do you still clone the GitHub repository locally, and push from it to your Google Cloud repository? From where do you want to push, to where?

Comment: I have a repository in github, and it's a website hosted in google cloud as a project. I want that everytime i do a push or a commit from my local to the repo automatically do the change in the google cloud project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want that everytime i do a push or a commit from my local to the repo automatically do the change in the google cloud project

That means a GitHub Action, and I do not see one which would directly push to your G-CSR ([Google Cloud Source Repository](https://source.cloud.google.com/onboarding/welcome)).

You would need to write one, which would:

- [checkout your GitHub repository](https://github.com/actions/checkout) on push
- [setup gcloud](https://github.com/google-github-actions/setup-gcloud)
- call a script like [`cloudfunction-python37.sh`](https://github.com/danieldsj/push-to-gcp/blob/master/cloudfunction-python37.sh) which will

  - Enable Google Cloud Source Repository API
    `gcloud services enable sourcerepo.googleapis.com;`
  - Add IAM permissions to default Cloud Build service account

    ```
    gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding \
      $PROJECT_ID@appspot.gserviceaccount.com \
      --member="serviceAccount:$PROJECT_NUMBER@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com" \
      --role="roles/iam.serviceAccountUser"
    ```
  - Add Google Cloud Source repository as remote to local Git repository
    `git remote add google https://source.developers.google.com/p/$PROJECT_ID/r/$REPO_NAME`
  - Do a git push

Comment: I´m gonna try it, thanks a lot